# dom4j not loading through entire xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, rss, persistence

I am doing this project that downloads the weather from the Yahoo! Weather rss feed and writing it to the database. The links to Yahoo! Weather: http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=95129
The problem right now is that it's not loading to the  tag. It can read all the other parts but it kinda stops after the astronomy tag. Can anyone tell me why this is not working? (Also, I am using Hibernate and JPA)

Here is my code:

```
public void testBasicUsage() {
        URL myURL;
        Document document;
        Element root;
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        try {
            myURL = new URL("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=95129");
            document = parse(myURL);        
            root = document.getRootElement();
            Element row;
            Iterator itr;
            for (Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                row = (Element) i.next();
                itr = row.elementIterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Element child = (Element) itr.next();
                    if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("yweather:location")){
                        String location = child.attributeValue("city") + ", " +  
                                child.attributeValue("region");
                        weather.setLocation(location);
                        System.out.println("location: " + location);
                    }else if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("yweather:wind")){
                        String chill = child.attributeValue("chill");
                        int direction = Integer.parseInt(child.attributeValue("direction"));
                        int speed = Integer.parseInt(child.attributeValue("speed"));
                        Wind wind = new Wind(chill,direction,speed);
                        weather.setWind(wind);
                        System.out.println("chill: " + chill + "; direction: " + direction + "; speed: " + speed);
                    }else if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("yweather:atmosphere")){
                        int humidity = Integer.parseInt(child.attributeValue("humidity"));
                        int visibility = Integer.parseInt(child.attributeValue("visibility"));
                        double pressure = Double.parseDouble(child.attributeValue("pressure"));
                        Atmosphere atmosphere = new Atmosphere(humidity,visibility,pressure);
                        weather.setAtmosphere(atmosphere);
                        System.out.println("humidity: " + humidity + "; visibility: " + visibility + "; pressure: " + pressure);
                    }else if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("yweather:astronomy")){
                        String sunrise = child.attributeValue("sunrise");
                        String sunset = child.attributeValue("sunset");
                        Astronomy astronomy = new Astronomy(sunrise,sunset);
                        weather.setAstronomy(astronomy);
                        System.out.println("sunrise: " + sunrise + "; sunset: " + sunset);
                    }else if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("yweather:condition")){
                        String text = child.attributeValue("text"); // condition text
                        int code = Integer.parseInt(child.attributeValue("code"));
                        int temp = Integer.parseInt(child.attributeValue("temp"));
                        String date = child.attributeValue("date");
                        Condition condition = new Condition(text,code,temp,date);
                        weather.setCondition(condition);
                        System.out.println("text: " + text + "; temp: " + temp + "; date: " + date);
                    }
                }
            }
            EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.persist(weather);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Document parse(URL url) throws DocumentException 
    {
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document document = reader.read(url);
        return document;
    }
```

And FYI, testBasicUsage() is a TestCase function that will be run by JUnit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry. I messed up the logic. I should have used selectNodes instead of the getElement thing. Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling tags after `<yweather:astronomy>`. Rest of the data is inside `<item>`and `<image>` tags:

```
else if (child.getQualifiedName().equals("item")){
    String title = child.elementText("title");
    System.out.println("title: " + title);
}
```